# Load a Scala File From Command Line

Tags: windows, scala, read-eval-print-loop

I'm fairly new to Scala and I'm having troubles running a .scala file from command line. I've tried the following commands

```
1.\PathToDirContaingingCode> scala myCode.scala

2.\PathToDirContaingingCode> scala
   scala> :load myCode.scala

3.\PathToDirContaingingCode> scala
   scala> :load \PathToDirContaingingCode\myCode.scala
```

All of these result in "That file does not exist"

I know that the code is correct because I've run it in the REPL already.

Comment: I'm using Windows, specifically 8 (unfortunately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found my answer.

```
\PathToDirContainingCode> scala
scala> :lo myCode.scala
```

The proper Scala command I was looking for was :lo